# Independent Events

Tags: probability, statistics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Independence and Events.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125401/independence-and-events)

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ are independent events.  How am I supposed to prove that:

1. $A'$ , $B'$ and $C'$ are independent and
2. $A, B'$ and $C'$ ,  are independent?

Thanks pals.